# How to view all xml_nodeset class object (output of rvest::html_nodes) in R?

Tags: r, rvest

If we create an object of class `xml_nodes` using `rvest`'s `html_nodes()`, how can we view all of the output in the R console

Example

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# Generate some sample html
a <- rep("<p></p>", 200) %>% paste0(collapse="")

a <- a %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("p")

a %>% length
# 200

# But only see first 20 (want to see all)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type in `print.AsIs(a)` to print the entire list.

(Truncated for brevity.)

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Setup data
a <- rep("<p></p>", 200) %>% paste0(collapse="")
a <- a %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("p")

# Print everything
print.AsIs(a)
#> [[1]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
...
#> 
#> [[197]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
#> 
#> [[198]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
#> 
#> [[199]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
#> 
#> [[200]]
#> {html_node}
#> <p>
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "xml_nodeset"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

You can also alter the `print()` function to print everything in a condensed way.

(Also truncated for brevity.)

```
# Alternative condensed printing
print(a, max_n = 200)
#> {xml_nodeset (200)}
#>   [1] <p></p>\n
#>   [2] <p></p>\n
#>   [3] <p></p>\n
...
#> [198] <p></p>\n
#> [199] <p></p>\n
#> [200] <p></p>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is really helpful and solves the problem. Do you know if there's anyway to print in the same format that the `xml_nodes` (it was more condensed than the output of `print.AsIs()`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a condensed version

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but I'm pretty sure R function parameter names will work so long as it is unique among all possible parameters. In other words, `print(a, ma=200)` will work as well.