# Why isn't max_n documented in base::print documentation?

Tags: r

It seems odd that such an important parameter should be not found in the base R package's documentation (`?base::print`)

I guess that it is perhaps encompassed by

> ...   further arguments passed to or from other methods.

Why is it not found under the 'Arguments' section of `?print`, and (assuming it is a parameter), where can its documented be found?

Comment: ?? Where are you getting this argument?  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @G5W it was provided to me in a another SO answer a long time ago, it's useful when using `rvest::html_nodes()` and you want to see > 20 results.

Comment: @G5W https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848838/5783745

Comment: `print` is a generic function. Many packages define classes which have their own version of `print`. The help file that you refer to says "It is a generic function which means that new printing methods can be easily added for new classes." Such printing method might define additional parameters. That is probably what is happening here. The documentation for the package that you are using is the natural place to look.

Comment: @JohnColeman very interesting! I must admit I don't fully understand how the custom behaviour is being defined. I do see reference to the class in question (`xml_nodeset`) [here](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/blob/master/R/classes.R#L91) though. I will have to read up. If anyone has any material to help understand how to give a class its own version of a generic function, please suggest

Comment: "Advanced R" by Hadley Wickham is perhaps the best source for understanding how R's class systems (note the plural) work. I have a physical copy, but I think that it is available for free online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I'd show how easy it is to write your own print method. You can create a new S3 class by simply giving an object a class name, using `class(x) <- "myclass"`, though usually you would do it a little more formally by having a function that does some type checking and returns an object with the appropriate structure as well as the class name:

```
make_stevec_obj <- function(x, message)
{
  structure(list(value = x, message = message), class = "stevec_class")
}
```

Now you create your own S3 print method for your new class like this:

```
print.stevec_class <- function(obj, max_n = 2)
{
  cat("An object of type 'stevec'\n")
  cat("values:", obj$value, "\n")
  cat("Repetitive message:", rep(obj$message, max_n))
}
```

So you can do:

```
make_stevec_obj(1:5, "hello world")
#> An object of type 'stevec'
#> values: 1 2 3 4 5 
#> Repetitive message: hello world hello world
```

And

```
x <- make_stevec_obj(1:5, "hello world")
print(x, max_n = 5)
#> An object of type 'stevec'
#> values: 1 2 3 4 5 
#> Repetitive message: hello world hello world hello world hello world hello world
```