# How to see available parameters and documentation for a class method in R?

Tags: r

How can we see all available parameters (or view documentation more generally) for a class method?

For example, if we look at arguments for `print()`

```r
?print

x   
an object used to select a method.

... 
further arguments passed to or from other methods.

quote   
logical, indicating whether or not strings should be printed with surrounding quotes.


-- leaving others out for brevity --
 
useSource   
logical indicating if internally stored source should be used for printing when present, e.g., if options(keep.source = TRUE) has been in use.
```

Note that we do not see any documentation for the parameter `max_n`.

Now suppose we call `print()` on something of class `xml_nodes`, e.g:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# Generate an object of class xml_nodes
a <- rep("<p></p>", 30) %>% 
  paste0(collapse="") %>% 
  read_html %>% 
  html_nodes("p")

class(a)
# [1] "xml_nodeset"
```

`a` is of class `xml_nodeset`, and if we call `print(a)`, it prints **only 20 results**, and that's because (I think) the xml_nodeset class is configured such that when `print` is called on it, it will only return 20 results. (the '20' number [can be changed via the `max_n` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58848838/5783745)).

How do we find the specific documentation for how `print` will behave when called on the object of class `xml_nodeset`? (preferably via RStudio/manuals)

Note that the example above is just a random example, I would like to find a general way of finding documentation for all class methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all the "special" version of print by running `methods(print)`. These versions are typically in the form `<function name>.<class name>`. Many listed there have astericks which means they are not directly exported from the packages where they are defined. If they have documentation, you can access it via `?print.rle` for example. In this case there is no documentation for the `print.xml_nodeset` function. But you can look at it if you do `getAnywhere(print.xml_nodeset)` or if you happened to know it was from the `xml2` namespace, you could do `xml2:::print.xml_nodeset` (with three colons).

There's also the `sloop` package which can tell you which S3 method will be called for a given invocation. For example

```
sloop::s3_dispatch(print(a))
=> print.xml_nodeset
 * print.default
```

You could file an issue with the package maintainer asking to provide documentation for the function, but otherwise R can't really give you documentation if the author did not include it.

Comment: Is it true to say that `?print.rle` simply returns the documentation for `?rle`?

Comment: @stevec Notice how both functions are documented at the top of the page (it shows the parameters for both). When available, the `print()` function is often documented on the same page that creates the type of object it's meant to print.

Comment: A lot of valuable info to take in here. If I understand correctly, a general approach is i) try `?function.class` (e.g. `?print.rle`. ii) If previous step returns "No documentation.. etc", then look for the source code via either `xml2:::print.xml_nodeset` or `getAnywhere(print.xml_nodeset) `. Is that  a sound general approach? Also, curious as to what `* print.default` tells us when using sloop?

Comment: Yes that's a good general approach. The `s3_dispatch` function shows you all the possible S3 methods that were considered and highlights the one what was chosen. So if the `print.xml_nodeset` function had not existed, it would have done to `print.default` instead.

Comment: One last question, how did you learn all this? Was it slowly over time or are there some references you'd recommend?

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, Hadley's [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) covers much of this stuff. That's where I learned about `sloop` for example.